# Eslint in VSCODE stops working (yet again)

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

Eslint stops working yet again..

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb"],
  "root": true,
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react-hooks",
    "react"
  ],
```

```
"rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error",
```

Using `VSCODE Version: 1.47.0-insider`

```
useEffect(() => {
 someVarOutside
}, []);
```

The above should warn that `someVarOutside` is missing from dep array. `react-hooks` ***was*** working. Now it is not.